# ehCache initialise + Load data from DB

Tags: initialization, ehcache, warm-up

I want to load all the static Data from DB during the ehCache Initialization.

What is the best approach to do this?

Is I have to configure any Loader in the cache configuration file? If yes when This loader will be called?

ehCache documentation - http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.4/user-guide/cache-loaders 
tells about some loader. But not able to under stand whether this is the best way to address my problem or not.